# size of mulitple file upload is 1 even if no files are attached

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

iam using spring boot to create application.

I have a form page which has some input fields and a file type of input

```
<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" id="uploadedFile" multiple accept=".pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png" />


public ModelAndView transferSingleAssetGarage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean,
            BindingResult result, MultipartFile[] uploadedFile)
```

everything works fine if i upload even a single file...

but the problem is when i dont upload any files the following statement prints 1

```
System.out.println("length is "+uploadedFile.length);
```

the above statement prints 1 even if i dont upload any files while submitting the form
also this statement `System.out.println(uploadedFile[i].getContentType())`
prints contentType as `application/octet-stream`

can somebody point the error in my code and why is the size of file array prints as 1 even when no file are uploaded.

Comment: Check the content... You probably get an array with a `null` element. The file element is part of the form so gets submitted without content, leading to a single `null` element in your array.

Comment: okay..,your point makes sense...but when i print uploadedFile[i].getContentType() it prints application/octet-stream

Comment: Then you probably have an empty `MultipartFile` in there. Also that argument should be annotated with `@RequestParam`, which I suspect might be the underlying cause for this issues.

Comment: i have used @RequestParam but still have the size is 1..well thanks for responding

Comment: The size will probably remain one but with either a `null`or  empty `MultiPartFile` elment (has a content typ ebut other properties content/size etc. are either null or 0).